# HTTP Error 500.1013 Azure App Service Node 8.9.4

Tags: node.js, azure, iis, azure-app-service-plans

We have used the Azure App Service on Linux/Docker to host our Node.js app, We have an error **500.1013** while sending more than **240MB** files in Request Body. (Node exe is crashed).

but it's working fine in development, We have faced this error only in production.

Web.config

```
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <clear />
      <add name="iisnode" path="app.js" verb="*" modules="iisnode" />
    </handlers>
    <httpErrors existingResponse="PassThrough" />
    <httpProtocol>
      <customHeaders>
        <remove name="X-Powered-By" />
      </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>
    <iisnode enableXFF="true" maxRequestBufferSize="52428800" loggingEnabled="true" />
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="Node app">
          <match url="/*" />
          <action type="Rewrite" url="app.js" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
    <security>
      <requestFiltering removeServerHeader="true">
        <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="2097152000" />
      </requestFiltering>
   </security>
   <webSocket enabled="false" />
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

App.js (proxy)

````
 config.get("apiBase"),
 {
   limit: "2gb",
   proxyReqOptDecorator: (proxyReqOpts, srcReq) => {

     const headerNames = Object.keys(proxyReqOpts.headers);
     headerNames.forEach(h => {
       if (h.startsWith("x-forwarded-")) {
         delete proxyReqOpts.headers[h];
       }
     });

     return proxyReqOpts;
   },
   proxyReqPathResolver: req => "/" + (req.path.substring(`/${apiProxyPathPrefix}/`.length) + "?" + (url.parse(req.url).query || ''))
 }); ```
````

Comment: Linux and Docker do not use your IIS settings.

Comment: Please suggest any solution for this issue

Comment: Was this issue resolved?